# Automatic tests for phonegap plugins

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, mobile, cordova

I recently wrote a phonegap plugin for Android and iOS (javascript calls native java or objc code and returns results via callback functions in javascript), is there anyway to have automatic testing for it (think ant, maven)? I currently have some asyncTests() using QUnit, but you have to manually see the app running either in the emulator/simulator or on a real device to see if the tests passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hej,
im dealing with this problem too. right now I ve found something like this http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36886195/Automated%20TestCases%20for%20PhoneGap and
http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/browse_thread/thread/723039be2c9df90e

so this may help ;]